# Couchbase SDK PHP have no intellisense in Visual Studio PHP Tool?

Tags: php, visual-studio, couchbase

From the warning I got:

> Class or interface 'CouchbaseCluster' used in PHPDoc is unknown.

From the warning, I assume PHP Tool itself doesn't know anything about 3rd Party SDK, so have no way to provide the intellisense or documentation.

Is there anyway I can manually add them into the PHPDoc?

Comment: The PHP SDK is primarily written in C, and as such cannot be parsed in the normal sense. There are some API stubs (https://github.com/couchbaselabs/php-couchbase/tree/master/stub) which you might be able to feed to your IDE, although that code isn't actually part of the module itself.